# Across Network, Get all active RDP connections and their address (Network going out)

Tags: windows, networking, rdp

Is it possible to set something up on our network so that we can see all outgoing RDP connections and the IP they're connected to?

We're constantly kicking each other off RDP connections, so some sort of internal tool that can be built on top of this functionality would be great.

Comment: Wireshark is ideal for this sort of network monitoring.

Comment: Why you are kikking out each other? Just allow more than one RDP session per user ...

Answer (score 1):

I've written a small script that is triggered by the RDP login and logoff events and writes the status to a little read-only share.

The clients run another script that first checks the RDP status on the share and when free fires up `mstsc`.